# AWS Lambda Timeout Handling - Return "Default" Value

Tags: python, aws-lambda, timeout, signals

For my lambda function, I want it to return a value from the lambda_handler before it times out. I am using Python, and I know I can use the signal library to trigger a signal handler function some amount of time before the lambda function times out. But how would I get this signal handler to make the lambda function to end and return a value?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # get the remaining time before timeout
    signal.alarm(int(context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() / 1000) - 5)
    
    # do some stuff that might take too long, write to output variable

    return output
    
    
def timeout_handler(_signal, _frame):
    # want to tell lambda function to return some set value
    # ...

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
```

I don't want the timeout handler to return an error.

I tried returning a value directly from the timeout_handler, but nothing happened. I'm assuming this is because the timeout handler just went back to what it was doing before the signal happened?